# How do I count duplicate rows with the Start Date is the same as above End Date using PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

How do I add count as 1,2,3,... to the number of duplicate rows with Start date equal to the above Row End Date (or End Date of a Row equal to below row Start Date) by using below sample query?.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXiSTS "Count";

CREATE TABLE "Count" ("Code" bigint, 
                       "Start Date" timestamp without time zone, 
                       "End Date" timestamp without time zone, 
                       "Extended" character varying(255), 
                       "Transaction ID" bigint, 
                       "ID #" character varying(255));
                       
INSERT INTO "Count" ("Code", 
                    "Start Date", 
                       "End Date", 
                       "Extended", 
                       "Transaction ID" , "ID #" )

VALUES (589373857, '06/23/2021 13:03:57', '06/23/2021 14:03:57', '0', 5843454160, '299SC4'),
        (589373857, '06/23/2021 13:19:22', '06/23/2021 13:43:22', '0', 5843383960, '299SC4'),
        (589373857, '06/23/2021 15:10:05', '06/23/2021 16:10:05', '0', 5843727220, '299SC4'),
        (589373857, '06/23/2021 16:10:05', '06/23/2021 17:10:05', 'yes', 5843596000, '299SC4'),
        (588633059, '06/23/2021 15:01:23', '06/23/2021 17:25:23', '0', 5843649640, '306SC4'),
        (583079912, '06/23/2021 09:30:02', '06/23/2021 09:42:02', '0', 5843471800, '338SC4'),
        (582553030, '06/23/2021 09:04:53', '06/23/2021 09:14:53', '0', 5843402680, '364SC4'),
        (583163101, '06/23/2021 09:16:11', '06/23/2021 09:28:11', '0', 5843518420, '364SC4'),
        (584063039, '06/23/2021 15:02:13', '06/23/2021 15:12:13', '0', 5843671240, '364SC4'),
        (582833001, '06/23/2021 09:01:54', '06/23/2021 10:01:54', '0', 5843480620, '438SC5'),
        (585803021, '06/23/2021 10:01:54', '06/23/2021 11:01:54', 'yes', 5843524900, '438SC5'),
        (585803021, '06/23/2021 11:01:54', '06/23/2021 12:01:54', 'yes', 5843522560, '438SC5'),
        (585803021, '06/23/2021 12:35:23', '06/23/2021 13:11:23', '0', 5843479540, '438SC5'),
        (585803021, '06/23/2021 13:11:23', '06/23/2021 13:23:23', 'yes', 5843551360, '438SC5'),
        (585803021, '06/23/2021 13:23:23', '06/23/2021 13:35:23', 'yes', 5843495380, '438SC5'),
        (585803021, '06/23/2021 14:11:37', '06/23/2021 15:11:37', '0', 5843489260, '438SC5'),
        (585803021, '06/23/2021 15:11:37', '06/23/2021 16:11:37', 'yes', 5843723260, '438SC5'),
        (585803021, '06/23/2021 16:11:37', '06/23/2021 16:47:37', 'yes', 5843623540, '438SC5'),
        (585803021, '06/23/2021 16:47:37', '06/23/2021 17:11:37', 'yes', 5843561260, '438SC5'),
        (585803021, '06/23/2021 17:11:37', '06/23/2021 17:23:37', 'yes', 5843673940, '438SC5'),
        (585803021, '06/23/2021 17:47:02', '06/23/2021 18:59:59', '0', 5843639380, '577SC5'),
        (584453015, '06/23/2021 15:39:24', '06/23/2021 16:39:24', '0', 5843734420, '584SC5');
```

I would like to the result query to be like below sample table. Please help.. Thank you

```
**Code    Start Date  End Date    Extended    Transaction ID  ID #    Counter**
589373857   6/23/2021 13:03 6/23/2021 14:03 0   5843454160  299SC4  0
589373857   6/23/2021 13:19 6/23/2021 13:43 0   5843383960  299SC4  0
589373857   6/23/2021 15:10 6/23/2021 16:10 0   5843727220  299SC4  1
589373857   6/23/2021 16:10 6/23/2021 17:10 yes 5843596000  299SC4  2
588633059   6/23/2021 15:01 6/23/2021 17:25 0   5843649640  306SC4  0
583079912   6/23/2021 9:30  6/23/2021 9:42  0   5843471800  338SC4  0
582553030   6/23/2021 9:04  6/23/2021 9:14  0   5843402680  364SC4  0
583163101   6/23/2021 9:16  6/23/2021 9:28  0   5843518420  364SC4  0
584063039   6/23/2021 15:02 6/23/2021 15:12 0   5843671240  364SC4  0
582833001   6/23/2021 9:01  6/23/2021 10:01 0   5843480620  438SC5  1
585803021   6/23/2021 10:01 6/23/2021 11:01 yes 5843524900  438SC5  2
585803021   6/23/2021 11:01 6/23/2021 12:01 yes 5843522560  438SC5  3
585803021   6/23/2021 12:35 6/23/2021 13:11 0   5843479540  438SC5  1
585803021   6/23/2021 13:11 6/23/2021 13:23 yes 5843551360  438SC5  2
585803021   6/23/2021 13:23 6/23/2021 13:35 yes 5843495380  438SC5  3
585803021   6/23/2021 14:11 6/23/2021 15:11 0   5843489260  438SC5  1
585803021   6/23/2021 15:11 6/23/2021 16:11 yes 5843723260  438SC5  2
585803021   6/23/2021 16:11 6/23/2021 16:47 yes 5843623540  438SC5  3
585803021   6/23/2021 16:47 6/23/2021 17:11 yes 5843561260  438SC5  4
585803021   6/23/2021 17:11 6/23/2021 17:23 yes 5843673940  438SC5  5
585803021   6/23/2021 17:47 6/23/2021 18:59 0   5843639380  577SC5  0
584453015   6/23/2021 15:39 6/23/2021 16:39 0   5843734420  584SC5  0
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. The pattern in your hoped-for **Counter** column is not obvious. For example, what is the **1** in the third row referring to? What is the **2** in the fourth row referring to? Can you clarify?

Comment: I'm trying to count the number of events a person made in a session. Use 1 to identify the first time event with an extended is 0 and use 2 for the next with an extended is yes. it follows 1,2,3,4,.. pattern. Since the first row End Date doesn't equal to below row Start Date, the counter is 0 so does the second row with an extended is 0. The third row End Date equal to below row Start Date with an extended is 0, it is 1 for counter. The fourth row follows the same pattern with counter 2 and extended is yes. I hope this is clear

Comment: Ah, OK, so 1 is the first event in the sequence, where its only connection is that the **End Date** matches, and the final event in the sequence will have only the **Start Date** matching, is that right? I'd do this with a function and a cursor, not in a single query. I'm not sure it's not possible in a single query, but it will be extremely complicated and brittle.

Comment: Yes, you are corrected. I tried using queries but they weren't working for me. I appreciate your help. Thanks.